# Angular 8 - display different value in input than ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive

I'm just trying to write a directive that will display a different value than the `ngModel`, by doing this:

`this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(maskedValue.result);`

but it seems to change the actual `ngModel` to the value, rather than just display the value.

```
import {
    Input,
    Directive,
    AfterContentInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { StringMask } from '@src/ngjs-src/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[mask]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})
export class MaskDirective implements AfterContentInit {
    @Input() public ngModel: string;
    @Input() public maskType: string;

    constructor(private model: NgModel) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public modelOptions: {};
    public ngModelOptions: {} = { allowInvalid: true };
    private mask: StringMask;

    public ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.mask = StringMask.GetStringMask(this.maskType);
        this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            if (value) {
                const maskedValue = this.mask.process(value);
                this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(maskedValue.result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

usage of the directive:

```
<cb-input type="text"
          name="accountNumber"
          label="Account Number"
          [required]="true"
          mask
          [maskType]="'BANK'"
          [(ngModel)]="mappedItem.accountNumber">
</cb-input>
```

How do I make the component display `maskedValue.result`, but not change the actual ngModel to `maskedValue.result`?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to accomplish - what goes in your model and what is displayed on your form?

Comment: @theMayer I want the model to be like “000123456789” and the form value displayed is like “000-1234-56789”. My string mask acts on the model to produce the displayed value. But the model seems to be getting changed to the displayed value when I do that.

Comment: You should also consider usability - modifying what the user is typing (even if just for display purposes) can disorient the user and cause usability problems - see [this article](http://ignorethecode.net/blog/2016/06/28/violating_user_expectations/) for a good explanation (I have a MS in human factors engineering, so am pretty well-versed on this topic). Tread carefully.

Comment: I would probably solve this by reformatting the input to match after the field loses focus.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins why don't you use a pipe?